# Bounds on moving average process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables and define the average process $\{Y_t\}$ as
$$
Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^p a_k X_{t-i}
$$
with some constants $a_1,\cdots,a_p \in \mathbb{R}$. This model includes the [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average) and [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing).

Are there any bounds or convergence rates for the difference $|Y_t - \mathbb{E}[X]|$ for any $t$ when the $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$ are bounded?

I know there is some work on large deviations for $S_n = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,\quad n=1,2,\dots$ e.g. by [T.Jiang et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030441499595687P) or Donsker and Varadhan (1985).

I suppose there exists already some work in this direction outside large deviations.

Comment: Small typo, $a_k$ should be $a_i$.

Comment: I assume that $\sum_{i=1}^pa_i=1$ ? Then $E[Y_t]=E[X]$. And you can easily compute the variance: $$E\left[|Y_t-E[X]|^2\right]=E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^pa_i(X_{t-i}-E[X])\right)^2\right]=Var(X)\sum_{i=1}^pa_i^2$$ It is not clear what you mean by convergence as this does not depend on $t$.